# Net Core development dependencies scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to resolve in the next scenario?

I ve got a CLIENTAPP

CLIENTAPP wants to load LIBRARY only when in local development.

If I use `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' "` in the csproj then I cant have injected services from LIBRARY to load in CLIENTAPP. For example If I want to do UseThing() in ConfigureServices method from clientapp.

I mean If I can have a library to use in local that is not going to be deployed but I don't need to remove calls from client code.

How to resolve here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a void method that the jitter will insert code to actually call only when the condition is met.  For a DEBUG build you can use something like this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void UseThing(parameters here)
{
   // use your thing with the parameters
}


public void Main(string[] args)
{
  UseThing(args);  // only called in DEBUG builds
  // rest of Main goes here
}
```

If you want to define your own compiler variable other than DEBUG you are free to do so.

Comment: I find your answer usefull since I didn't know that way. But sadly when I purpose to do a "conditional" reference it fails when I try other configuration different of "DEBUG". Of course he can not find reference for the call to the library method. I think what I try is not posible. But usefull If we decide to make some building references and so on. Still we can manage to activate or not manually. Thanks @NoRefundsNoReturns.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2 is a link to the attribute.  Maybe you  need to fully qualify it with [System.Diagnostics.Conditional]. I've used this numerous time and have PROD code using it as I write this.  Super useful.